# Problem with Ubercart post upgrading jQuery to 6.x-2.0-alpha1

Tags: theming, ubercart

I have Mucho menu module installed and it dose not support jQuery 1.5 on D6, So I updated the jQuery module to latest 6.x-2.0-alpha1. Post upgrading the muchomenu works, but ubercart payment process stopped working... i see a progress bar loading and never stops on checkout page.

How to make both the modules work? could someone please point me to the correct path?

Thanks,
Anand

Comment: Do you see any Javascript errors in Chrome Console or using firebug ?

Comment: No, I don't see any errors on both the browsers

Comment: Ubercart payment works when I downgrade the jQuery back to 1.5. But the MuchoMenu module dose not work (the dropdown dose not open up)  :(

Comment: Oh.. sorry, I see below error on chrome:
Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [@name*=delivery_country]